# Loop doesn't end. How do I get out of a loop?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to generate and print out 5 numbers from 1 to 5, but not in sequence. I'm using a self-written function, 'appearBefore' that will check whether the number has appeared before.

The function appearBefore will return '0' if the number has not appeared before, and '1' if the function has appeared before.

At the moment, the do-while loop doesn't get out of the loop even when 0 is returned. The program never ends. Any recommendations on what I can do?

EDITS - The downvotes sure comes fast. I have added the counter++, but it still does not work. Perhaps someone can advice on the inner-loop?

```
while (count < 5) {

    repeat = 1; 

    do {
        randomNumber = rand() % 4 + 1;
        cout << randomNumber;
        repeat = appearBefore(randomNumber);
        cout << " " << repeat << endl;

    } while (repeat == 1);

    //Add the number into an array of numbers that have appeared before
    checker[counterForChecker] = randomNumber;
    counterForChecker++;

    counter++;
}
```

This is the function appearBefore (the variables are global variables):

```
int appearBefore(int number) {

    int x = 0;
    int match = 0;

    while (x < counterForChecker+1) {
        if (checker[x] == number) {
            match = 1;
            break;
        }
        else {
            match = 0;
        }
        x++;
    }

    return match;
}
```

Comment: Where is `count` being incremented ?

Comment: You use count < 5 in your while loop bit never change its value inside the loop.  Did you mean to use count or something else?

Comment: Don't use `int` when you mean `bool`.

Answer (score 4):

You check for `count < 5` while increasing `counterForChecker`.

---

Set the while condition to

```
while (counterForChecker < 5)
```

**or** increase the counter

```
counter++; // counterForChecker++;
```

Comment: Hi. I have increased the counter++ but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming that `counter++;` actually says `count++;`...)

If `x` and `k` are positive, `x % k` is a number between `0` and `k - 1`.

So you have four possible values to choose from (1,2,3,4), and you're looping until you've found five unique values.
That will never end well.

To generate numbers from 1 to 5, use `rand() % 5 + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change the variable count. This is now not done, so since the value does not change the loop will not end.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is running while `count < 5` and you never increment `count`.

Did you mean to use:

```
while (counterForChecker < 5)
```

If not, add:

```
++count;
```

at the end of the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Use a debugger and step through the code, looking at the values of the variables as you do so.  You'll learn more about how everything is working.